# C++ operator used when creating a new object

Tags: c++

I have a question about the way objects are created in C++. If I define a class, say `CSomeClass`, I can create a new object of `CSomeClass` using the following line:

```
CSomeClass* pSomeClass = new CSomeClass;
```

and in this case I also have the ability to control the way the new object is created by overriding ***new*** operator. My question is, when I use the following line of code

```
CSomeClass pSomeClass;
```

What operator is being used to create the object in this case. I'd like to be able to override that particular operator in the same manner that I can the new operator but I'm not sure which that would be. If this question doesn't quite make sense, please let me know and I'll clarify. Thanks.

Comment: You can only override operator new which is responsible for memory allocation, but not new operator.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, no operator is involved. There is nothing to override.

Comment: The reason i need to do this is so that I can determine which heap the object is written to. How would I do this in the case of the second line in my example? Thanks everyone for the feedback.

Comment: @user399540 You can't it's on the stack not on the heap in the second line.

Comment: @user399540: What P3trus said - why would you even care where the object lives? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @P3trus - Thanks for the info, after further reading last night i realized that it would be on the stack instead of the heap and then your answer confirmed it. -- Georg, the reason i was asking was that i'm creating an application in which each thread would work with it's own heap, whenever I'm instantiating a new object i wanted to make sure it was on correct heap and so would have to override operator new to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to be able to override the latter. The "new" operator is override-able to allow optimizations in allocating, for instance, using a slab allocater, etc. But when you create a variable on the stack, there is no decision to be made as to where it is placed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the creation of the object, you want to create a default constructor, not override the `new` operator.

In your header file:

```
class CSomeClass
{
public:
    CSomeClass();
}
```

And then in your definition file:

```
CSomeClass::CSomeClass()
{
    // Initialize your object here
}
```

That is, unless I misunderstood the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CSomeClass* pSomeClass = new CSomeClass;
```

Here you create a dynamic object of the class CSomeClass. The compiler calls the no-argument constructor.

```
CSomeClass pSomeClass;
```

You create non-dynamic object of the class CSomeClass. The compiler calls EXACTLY the same no argument constructor.

You can use operator new to allocate memory for dynamic variables:

```
int *number= new int(1);
```